# How to use #states with Heirarchichal Select?

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I want to show a field based on the value of an taxonomy in hierarchical select in Node Add form.I am using #states for it but i can't find where the value of the heirarchichal select is stored or how it is selected. This is how i tried to do it using hook_form_alter.

```
$form['field_name']['#states'] =  array (
      'visible' => array (   // action to take.
        'select[name="field_category[und][hierarchical_select][selects][0]"]' => array('value' => '62'),

      ),
    );
```

When the value of heirarchichal select is 62,i want to show it?